# Select threshold for binary classification using desired fpr value

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, classification, catboost

I want to recreate `catboost.utils.select_threshold`([desc](https://catboost.ai/en/docs/concepts/python-reference_utils_get_roc_curve)) method for `CalibratedClassifierCV` model.

In Catboost I can select desired fpr value, **to return the boundary at which the given FPR value is reached**.

My goal is to the same logic after computing fpr, tpr and boundaries from `sklearn.metrics.roc_curve`

I have the following code

```
prob_pred = model.predict_proba(X[features_list])[:, 1]
            
fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(X['target'], prob_pred)

optimal_idx = np.argmax(tpr - fpr) # here I need to use FPR=0.1
boundary = thresholds[optimal_idx]
 
binary_pred = [1 if i >= boundary else 0 for i in prob_pred]
```

I guess it should be simple formula but I am not sure how to place 0.1 value here to adjust threshold.

Answer (score 1):

I've done my research and testing and it's that simple:

```
def select_treshold(proba, target, fpr_max = 0.1 ):
    # calculate roc curves
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(target, proba)
    # get the best threshold with fpr <=0.1
    best_treshold = thresholds[fpr <= fpr_max][-1]
    
    return best_treshold
```